# MySQL compare each tuple to each other tuple in the same relation

Tags: mysql, sql

Relations:
Product(maker, model, type)
Laptop(Model, price, speed, ram, hd, screen)
PC(model, price, speed, ram, hd)
Printer(model,price, color, price)

I am trying to find pc's who share both the same speed and same ram.

What I have tried:

```
SELECT model FROM pc WHERE pc.speed = pc.speed AND pc.ram = pc.ram;
```

This is again (If you have seen my list of questions from today), that this is the wrong syntax.

I want to compare each tuple in pc to each other tuple in pc and create a new relation based on a pc's speed and ram sharing anothers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT pc1.model, pc2.model 
FROM 
    pc pc1 
    JOIN pc pc2 
        ON pc1.speed = pc2.speed 
        AND pc1.ram = pc2.ram
        AND pc1.model <> pc2.model
```

Note that this will return two rows for every match... `A <-> B` and `B <-> A`.  If you want to prevent this, you can change your query to something like the following:

```
SELECT pc1.model, pc2.model 
FROM 
    pc pc1 
    JOIN pc pc2 
        ON pc1.speed = pc2.speed 
        AND pc1.ram = pc2.ram
        AND pc1.model > pc2.model
```

Comment: So are creating two sub tables pc1 and pc2, and defining them as copies of pc, joining them on the basis that pc1.speed = pc2.speed and pc1.ram = pc2.ram. But what does the last AND pc1.model > pc2.model do exactly?

Comment: The query joins the table to itself.  The first query won't join the exact same record to itself by saying that `model` can't be equal.  The second query will return only 1 record for a match by saying that the `model` on the left side of the join must be greater than the `model` on the right side of the join...  It would work just as well with a `<`...

Comment: Self-join will return all possible pairs, quite a lot if there are many models with the same speed and ram. I'd rather use group by with group_concat.